# R- Can't predict with randomForest

Tags: r, random-forest, predict

I have a training set with 14 variables (13 predicting and 1 response) and a test set with 13 variables (13 predicting, with exact same name as ones in training set). Here is the details:

```
> str(kaggletrain)
'data.frame':   1861 obs. of  14 variables:
 $ condit        : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ condition     : Factor w/ 6 levels "For parts or not working",..: 6 6 6 4 5 6 3 3 6 6 ...
 $ good          : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ ipad          : num  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ new           : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ scratch       : num  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ screen        : num  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ this          : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ use           : num  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ work          : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ sold          : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 2 2 ...
 $ WordCount     : int  45 100 0 0 100 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ biddable      : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 2 1 1 1 2 2 1 2 2 ...
 $ productionline: Factor w/ 12 levels "iPad 1","iPad 2",..: 2 2 4 9 12 9 8 10 1 4 ...
> str(kaggletest)
'data.frame':   798 obs. of  13 variables:
 $ condit        : num  0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ condition     : Factor w/ 6 levels "For parts or not working",..: 6 6 6 6 2 4 5 6 6 6 ...
 $ good          : num  0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 ...
 $ ipad          : num  0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 ...
 $ new           : num  1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ scratch       : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ screen        : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ this          : num  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 ...
 $ use           : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ work          : num  0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 ...
 $ WordCount     : int  8 106 99 0 99 88 33 25 101 0 ...
 $ biddable      : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 ...
 $ productionline: Factor w/ 10 levels "iPad 1","iPad 2",..: 1 8 3 7 3 6 1 4 3 1 ...
```

I build a `randomForest` model on training set and it works fine. However, when I go ahead and use `predict` on test set, I encounter this error:

```
> bestrf = randomForest(sold~.,data=kaggletrain,mtry=3,ntree=400)
> pred.rf = predict(bestrf,kaggletest)
Error in predict.randomForest(bestrf, kaggletest) : 
  Type of predictors in new data do not match that of the training data.
```

As you can see, the predicting variables' names are exactly the same between training and test set. There is 1 predicting variable, which has 12 levels in training set and 10 levels in testing set (I think this should be fine). I use `predict` with logistics regression model on this dataset and it works too. So I am not sure where I did wrong. Really appreciate any help.

Comment: It's your word against the error message. Offer more evidence, please.

Comment: Although R shouldn't crash on the variable with less levels, it's still best to make sure that the underlying levels match (just to make sure it uses the correct levels to predict).
However, it seems to me that something as follows happens: a variable which is a factor in the training set and a character in the test set.  Could be other class inconsistences as well.

Comment: Already edited, please take a look. Classes in training and test set are the same

Comment: try to link to the actual data